# Double integral solution using scipy.integrate.nquad doesn't match integrate.dblquad

Tags: python, math, scipy, integral, mismatch

The **first function** in the code below uses double integration with `scipy.integrate.dblquad` to calculate the differential entropy, `c*np.log(c)`, of a copula density function `c`, which has one dependence parameter, `theta`, usually positive.

[image]

The **second function** in the code below tries to solve the same problem as above, but using the multiple integral solver `scipy.integrate.nquad`

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

def dblquad_(theta):
    "Double integration"
    c = lambda v, u: ((1+theta)*(u*v)**(-1-theta)) * (u**(-theta)+v**(-theta)-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.dblquad(
        lambda u,v: c(v,u)*np.log(c(v,u)), 
        0, 1, lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1
        )[0]

def nquad_(n,theta):
    "Multiple integration"
    c = lambda *us: ((1+theta)*np.prod(us)**(-1-theta)) * (np.sum(np.power(us,-theta))-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.nquad(
        func   = lambda *us : c(*us)*np.log(c(*us)), 
        ranges = [(0,1) for i in range(n)],
        args   = (theta,) 
        )[0] 

n=2
theta = 1
print(dblquad_(theta))
print(nquad_(n,theta))
```

The `dblquad`-based function gives an answer of `-0.7127`, while the `nquad` gives `-0.5823` and noticeably takes longer. Why are the solutions different even though I have set both to solve an `n=2`-dimensional problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the values of `n` and `theta` you provided, the output of your code is:

```
-0.1931471805597395
0.17055845832017144,
```

not `-0.7127` and `-0.5823`.

The first value (`-0.1931471805597395`) is the correct one (you can check it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f5f3cbf14f4f5d6d2085bf2d0fb76e8a) for yourself).

The problem in `nquad_` lies with the handling of the `theta` parameter. Thanks @mikuszefski for providing the explanation; I copy it here for clarity:

> `nquad` passes `lambda` to the function as required. The lambda is
> programmed in such a way that it accepts arbitrary number of
> arguments, so it happily takes it and puts it in the list of powers
> and sums. Hence you do not get, e.g. `1/u**t+1/v**t -1` but
> `1/u**t+1/v**t + 1/t**t -1`. The function call just does not match the
> intended function use. If you instead would write `us[0]**() + us[1]**() - 1` it works.

Here is the modified code:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

def dblquad_(theta):
    "Double integration"
    c = lambda v, u: ((1+theta)*(u*v)**(-1-theta)) * (u**(-theta)+v**(-theta)-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.dblquad(
        lambda u,v: c(v,u)*np.log(c(v,u)),
        0, 1, lambda u: 0, lambda u: 1
        )[0]

def nquad_(n,theta):
    "Multiple integration"
    c = lambda *us: ((1+theta)*np.prod((us[0], us[1]))**(-1-theta)) * (np.sum(np.power((us[0], us[1]),-theta))-1)**(-1/theta-2)
    return -integrate.nquad(
        func   = lambda *us : c(*us)*np.log(c(*us)),
        ranges = [(0,1) for i in range(n)],
        args=(theta,)
        )[0]

n=2
theta = 1
print(dblquad_(theta))
print(nquad_(n,theta))
```

Output:

```
-0.1931471805597395
-0.1931471805597395
```

Comment: Given that you have found that there is a determinate solution for the double integral using a parametric input, `c(theta)`, would you say that this is indicative that a closed-form solution can be derived for the math formula shown?

Comment: BTW the parameter `theta` is not misused. `nquad`passes it to the function as required. The `lambda` is programmed in such a way that it accepts arbitrary number of arguments, so it happily takes it and puts it in the list of powers and sums. Hence you do not get, e.g. `1/u**t+1/v**t -1` but `1/u**t+1/v**t + 1/t**t -1`. The function call just does not match the intended function use. If you instead would write `us[0]**() + us[1]**() - 1` it works.

Comment: @develarist the integral of `c(u,v)` actually has a closed form. `c * log c` probably not.

Comment: which article did you see `c`'s closed-form solution for its integral?

Comment: mathematically, why does `nquad_(n=3,theta)` give the exact same solution as the bivariate copula `nquad_(n=2,theta)` while taking twice as long to compute? Shouldn't higher-dimensional copulas be affected differently by the same level of `theta`? If not, does this mean that solving for bivariate copulas will already give me higher-dimension copula results?